# Conditionally sorting `Table` data on focus change causes AttributeGraph cycle error

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-table

Goal: macOS SwiftUI, sortable Table, double-click-to-edit-cell-contents. Focused on just String for now.

Passing a binding (e.g., `TableColumn("Title", value: \.Binding<Track>.title, ...)`) worked great to modify the content.

However, TextField (for String) updates its value binding on *each keypress*. Table sorts via the same binding, so as the user types, the row is re-sorted on each keypress. Woof.

Considered options:

1. Create `Formatter` subclass (TextField with a non-String requires formatter, + doesn't exhibit that trait)
2. Read `@FocusState`, dupe our `tracks` array, and only save the new val when the focus state changes.

Did number 2. However, I'm getting this strange output.

```swift
Focused: Optional(Field.text) -> Optional(Field.text)

=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 827216 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 827216 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 827216 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 827976 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 817860 ===
Focused: nil -> nil
```

(And shoutout to onChange not reading right. Good job, buddy!)

Reduced code example:

```swift
struct TrackList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    @State private var sortedTracks: [Binding<Track>] = []

    var body: some View {
        Table(of: Binding<Track>.self, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            TableColumn(
                "Title", 
                value: \Binding<Track>.wrappedValue, 
                comparator: titleComparator) 
            { trackBinding in
                TextField("Title", text: trackBinding.title)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .text)
            }
        } rows: {
            ForEach(sortedTracks) { $track in
                TableRow($track)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Since the new `.onChange(_ of:initial:)` isn't until macOS v14, we gotta do this for now.
            sortedTracks = $store.tracks.sorted(using: sortOrder)
        }
        .onChange(of: focusedField) { newValue in
            print("Focused: \(focusedField.debugDescription) -> \(newValue.debugDescription)")
            sortedTracks = $store.tracks.sorted(using: sortOrder)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this still occurs with the new `.onChange(of:initial:)` modifier, and removing `.onAppear` -- the only change is the debug line prints correctly, showing nil -> .text and .text -> nil states, respectively.